# Declare variable memory allocation VBA

Tags: vba, variables, memory

When we declare a variable or instantiate an object in VBA, is the memory that is allocated in the RAM memory, Cache memory or ROM memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the [RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM).

ROM means [Read-Only Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory), so obviously you won't write there.

As far as I know, VBA doesn't decide what goes to cache and what doesn't.

Comment: Thank you very much i was suspecting it but i needed someone who was not in beginner mode to verify also.